# Simple App Crashes on Launch

Tags: android, launch

Hello stackoverflow community,

I recently began learning and coding android applications. For my first app, I decided to create a simple app where you press a button (when you go to the bathroom) and the count goes up in an editable text field. There is also a reset button. On launch in an emulator, it opens to where I can see the app title but then crashes unexpectedly. Code is below, please help:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.CPTech.bathroomtracker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int TOTAL_TRIPS = 0;

    private EditText tripsNumberEditText;       
    Button bathroomTripButton;
    Button resetButton;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tripsNumberEditText.setText(TOTAL_TRIPS);

        bathroomTripButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bathroomTripButton);

        bathroomTripButton.setOnClickListener(bathroomTripButtonListener);

        resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);

        resetButton.setOnClickListener(resetButtonListener);

        tripsNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tripsNumberEditText);

    }

    public OnClickListener bathroomTripButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TOTAL_TRIPS++;
            tripsNumberEditText.setText(TOTAL_TRIPS);

        }

    };

    public OnClickListener resetButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TOTAL_TRIPS = 0;
            tripsNumberEditText.setText(TOTAL_TRIPS);

        }


    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

MainActivity.xml:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/dark_blue"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bathroomTripButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/ash_grey"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/bathroom_trip_button"
             />


    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/todayTripsTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/today_trips"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="16pt" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tripsNumberEditText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20pt"
            android:background="@color/davy_grey"
            android:ems="2" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resetButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/ash_grey"
            android:text="@string/reset_count" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
10-23 10:43:13.230: D/AndroidRuntime(837): Shutting down VM
10-23 10:43:13.230: W/dalvikvm(837): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.CPTech.bathroomtracker/com.CPTech.bathroomtracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.CPTech.bathroomtracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is in this line MainActivity.java:23

Comment: `10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 10:43:13.340: E/AndroidRuntime(837):  at com.CPTech.bathroomtracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)` is the key to tracking down the problem.

Comment: Note that storing a total in an Activity object member variable isn't going to be very useful, as it will be cleared every time the Activity is recreated, such as if the process needs to be removed from the background to provide resources for other apps, or even something as simple as rotating the orientation of the phone if you haven't configured the Manifest to ignore orientation changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this line

```
tripsNumberEditText.setText(TOTAL_TRIPS);
```

is giving your `NPE` because you haven't yet initialized it. Move this line below the initialization

```
tripsNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tripsNumberEditText);
tripsNumberEditText.setText(TOTAL_TRIPS);
```

**Will be your next error**

Also, you are using the wrong `setText()` method. You are giving it an `int` which will tell it to look for a `resource` with that `id` which it obviously won't find. You need to change it to a `String` with something like

```
tripsNumberEditText.setText("" + TOTAL_TRIPS);
```

[See the overloaded methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29)

Furthermore, since you are setting the text in `onCreate()` before the user has a chance to give any input, you could also set it in your xml with

```
android:text="0"
```

**Note** if you use a hard-coded string like this Eclipse will give you a warning which would be ok but better to define the value in `strings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this, you have accessed `tripsNumberEditText` before instantiating it

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        bathroomTripButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bathroomTripButton);

        bathroomTripButton.setOnClickListener(bathroomTripButtonListener);

        resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);

        resetButton.setOnClickListener(resetButtonListener);

        tripsNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tripsNumberEditText);

        tripsNumberEditText.setText(TOTAL_TRIPS);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

run this line:

`tripsNumberEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tripsNumberEditText);`

BEFORE this line:

`tripsNumberEditText.setText(TOTAL_TRIPS);`

in `onCreate()`